# Express.js calling next() async in middleware doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, middleware

I am trying to verify a request in express using a middleware which sends parts of the request to another server (g-captcha or whatever). I am having the problem, that I want to call the next()-function after that happened (async) which does not work.

The following code just uses the body-package to parse the body, but since it does it async, it still doesn't work.

```
const body = require('body/json');

httpServer = express();
httpServer.use((req, res, next) => {
    body(req, res, (err, body) => {
        console.log(body); // <- gets logged
        next(); // <- nothing happens
    });
});
```

I am working in typescript, but I cant imagine that to be a problem. The version of express is 4.15.4

Comment: Can you specify what _"does not work"_ and _"nothing happens"_ actually means?

Comment: Check the `err` parameter in callback.

Comment: Show us the next middleware

Comment: I figured it out myself, problem was, that the following middleware that wouldnt be able to consume the changed req-object.